# Порядок выполнения условий в блоке WHERE запроса SQL на БД ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Пример SQL запроса

```
select 1 
  from dual
 where condition1 
    or condition2
```

В ходе прочтения книги по oracle от Прибыл/Фейрштейн встречал, что ORACLE при отборах использующих OR действует следующим образом

1. Если condition1 - TRUE, то осуществляем выборку без проверки condition2
2. Иначе condition1 - FALSE, то переходим к проверке condtition2

Верно ли это?

Попытка найти это в книге не дала положительного результата

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что condition1 - константное выражение, вычисляемое на стадии подготовки плана, или спрашиваете об обработке отдельной записи на этапе выполнения запроса? Если первое - да, верно, запрос будет "упрощён", если второе - а сервер его знает... хотя вряд ли.

Comment: "Верно ли это?" Нет, не верно. Порядок выполнения заранее неизвестен.

Comment: @0xdb все же частично верно. Если на шаге построения плана уже понятно, что первое условие всегда истина, то условие вообще проверяться не будет

Comment: @Viktorov Ну  1=1 я не имел ввиду, это вроде и так понятно.

Comment: @0xdb согласен, это разумно. Но учитывая что такой вопрос вообще появился, лучше сказать явно )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL в общем случае - это декларативный язык. Вы говорите что хотите получить, но не говорите как. СУБД сама решает, как именно получать ваши данные.

Например Oracle может(и почти всегда будет) переписывать ваши запросы для построения наиболее оптимального плана. По этому в общем случае вы вообще не можете быть уверены, что ваш запрос будет иметь такой же вид. И практическое применение ваших знаний не зависимо от результат особо не имеет смысл.

Однако можно попробовать понять, что происходит с планом запроса для вашего примера.

Запрос:

```
select 1 
  from dual 
 where 1=1 
    or 1 != 1
```

План:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 1388734953 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation        | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|  1 |   FAST DUAL      |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Видим, что Oracle знал заранее что первый аргумент ВСЕГДА True и просто вообще исключил ее из плана запроса.

Попробуем чуть усложнить пример:

```
create table tst(id number, text varchar2(10));
insert into tst values(1, null);
insert into tst values(2, 'text');

select 1 
  from tst 
 where id in (1, 2) 
    or text != 'Дядушка Шу'
```

План:

```
Plan Hash Value  : 4148258400 

---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    2 |    40 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 1 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | TST  |    2 |    40 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - filter("TEXT"<>'Дядушка Шу' OR "ID"=1 OR "ID"=2)


Note
-----
- dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

Видим в плане запрос был переписан и условие `where` теперь больше похоже на `where "TEXT"<>'Дядушка Шу' OR "ID"=1 OR "ID"=2`

**Вывод:**
Логично предположить, что оптимизация описанная вами используется в Oracle как и во многих ЯП. Однако, не зависимо от того, в каком порядке и как обрабатываются условия в логическом выражении вы не можете на это полагаться для решения практических задач при написании `sql`, так как вы не управляете планом запроса и итоговый запрос может отличаться от вашего.

Comment: Отличный ответ, ап.

Comment: @0xdb, полностью поддерживаю) С конкретными и понятными примерами такие ответы гораздо ценнее